# Use sample function sample() to replace NA in R with some criteria

Tags: r

I have dataset with some values missing, now I need to use `sample()` function to impute 10 times to replace NA, but there are more requirements for `sample()` function.

```
ID <- c(rep(1,4), rep(3, 5), rep(4,4),rep(5,5),rep(6,5))
Begin <- c(0,2.5,3.5,3,7,8,7,25,25,10,15,0,0,1,NA,10,11,13,NA,NA, 8, 12, NA)
End <- c(1.5,3.5,NA,6,12,8,11,29,35, 12,19,NA,28,5,20,30,20,25,6,7,13,NA, 23)
GA <- c(23, 34, 38, 16, 20, 38, 32, 28, 30, 34,25,45,34,23, 34, 38, 16, 20, 38, 32, 28, 30, 34)
df <- data.table(ID, Begin, End, GA)
   ID Begin  End GA
 1:  1   0.0  1.5 23
 2:  1   2.5  3.5 34
 3:  1   3.5   NA 38
 4:  1   3.0  6.0 16
 5:  3   7.0 12.0 20
 6:  3   8.0  8.0 38
 7:  3   7.0 11.0 32
 8:  3  25.0 29.0 28
 9:  3  25.0 35.0 30
10:  4  10.0 12.0 34
11:  4  15.0 19.0 25
12:  4   0.0   NA 45
13:  4   0.0 28.0 34
14:  5   1.0  5.0 23
15:  5    NA 20.0 34
16:  5  10.0 30.0 38
17:  5  11.0 20.0 16
18:  5  13.0 25.0 20
19:  6    NA  6.0 38
20:  6    NA  7.0 32
21:  6   8.0 13.0 28
22:  6  12.0   NA 30
23:  6    NA 23.0 34
```

1. Group by ID
2. If we sample End Variable, Range of NA, need to smaller than GA, greater than Begin, greater than previous row, and smaller than next row.
3. If we sample Begin Variable, Range of NA, need to smaller then End variable, but greater than previous row of End

Example:

Row 3, End variable is NA, so that when we sample, that NA needs to be in the range [3.5,6]

Row 12, End variable is NA, that NA need to be in the range[19,28]

Row 15, Begin is NA, so NA >= 5 & NA <=20 and NA <= 34, so range [5,20]

Row 19, Begin is NA, [0,6]

Row 20, Begin is NA, NA >= 6, NA <= 7, so range [6,7]

Row 22, End is NA, range of NA [13,23]

Row 23, Begin is NA, NA >= value we just sample for row 22, NA <= 23

Comment: So, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I sympathize with those who are constrained to do this in English when it's not their natural language, but please go through your question and see if you can correct the grammatical errors. I don't understand it sufficiently well to do that for you.

Comment: I am almost done, I will rewrite later

Comment: If a NA in Begin has to be greater than the End in the previous row, why can there be something like row 3:  1   3.5   NA 38 and 4:  1   3.0  6.0 16 where the Begin of row 4 is smaler than the End of row 3?

Comment: It's over lap, so I need to recode Begin first, make sure it's not over lap.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this covers all special cases (e.g. if there many NAs), but for the given sample it should work.

There may be also a better solution, that doesn't include creating the variable `_pre` and `_next`.

I used a for-loop to create the values rowise (by `INDEX`). Instead of `sample()` I used `runif()` because I think you don't want to get only integers.

```
df[, INDEX := 1:.N]
df[, End_next := shift(End, type = "lead")]
df[, End_pre := shift(End, type = "lag")]
df[, ID_pre := shift(ID, type = "lag")]
df[, ID_next := shift(ID, type = "lead")]

for (i.row in c(1:dim(df)[1])) {
  # i.row = 3
  # adjust the values after last sample
  df[, Begin_pre := shift(Begin, type = "lag")]
  df[, End_pre := shift(End, type = "lag")]

  # replace NA with sample (runif)
  df[is.na(Begin) & INDEX == i.row,
     Begin := runif(1, min = ifelse(ID_pre == ID, End_pre,0), max = End)]
  df[is.na(End) & INDEX == i.row,
     End := runif(1, min = max(Begin, ifelse(ID_pre == ID, End_pre, Begin)),
                     max = min(GA, ifelse(ID_next == ID, End_next, GA)))]
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks, after took a look all of special cases, I think I should sample End first, and then sample Begin, it is more make sense trying to sample both at the same time